# VSCode will not open files in new tabs from integrated terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, remote-server

I opened up a remote workspace after a couple months without working on the project and I find that I can no longer open files in new tabs using the integrated terminal. After some Googling, this seems to be similar to the topic 69417211 but there was no resolution there. This is the result I get with 'verbose':

```
code file.txt --verbose
[70606:0302/113210.012652:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(1402)] Unable to open X display.
The futex facility returned an unexpected error code.
```

I don't know what 'futex' is and I don't know why it is looking for an X display. I tried installing the "remote development" extension locally but that didn't change anything. I can still open files using the browser, but that is not always an option and rarely convenient.

Local VSCode About:

Version: 1.64.2 (user setup)
Commit: f80445acd5a3dadef24aa209168452a3d97cc326
Date: 2022-02-09T22:02:28.252Z
Electron: 13.5.2
Chromium: 91.0.4472.164
Node.js: 14.16.0
V8: 9.1.269.39-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19044

Remote:
Visual Studio Code 1.64.2

Comment: I'm noticing that in previous instances of logging in, 'code' is available in ".vscode-server/bin/<hash>/bin/code" While today I have code-server there, and 'code' is in remote-cli directory. If I call 'code' from remote-cli folder directly, files are opened correctly. So the question becomes, why is this not being added to my path now? And why do I have 'code-server' instead of 'code' there?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution here:

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/6289

Basically, the 'inheritEnv' box needs to be checked. After closing and reopening a terminal, 'code' note works as expected.